# Test connection to server using c#

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

I want to test if server is alive for given `IPEndpoint`. I tried the following method but it sometimes returns the wrong result.

```
public bool IsAlive(IPEndPoint ipEndPoint)
{
  if (ipEndPoint == null) return false;

  var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
  var bConnect = tcpClient.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint.Address, ipEndPoint.Port, null, null);
  var isAlive = bConnect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
  return isAlive;
}
```

What is wrong about this method?

Comment: Please can you expand on what you mean by "it sometimes returns [the] wrong result"?

Comment: Sure, I am testing this method with following code. 

`while (true)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(IsAlive(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234)).ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
`

Comment: It Sometimes prints true and sometimes false.

Comment: Please edit the test code into your question.

Comment: Just because `AsyncWaitHandle` finished without timing out does not mean it connected ***successfully***

Comment: @ScottChamberlain please provide your implementation

Comment: A nanosecond after your method has returned a particular value, it may already be out of date. *In general*, there's no point in running checks like these since they don't answer the question of whether, at some point in the future, you will be able to accomplish a particular task. You're going to have to write code that copes with e.g. a server going down half-way through a transmission gracefully *anyway*, and once that code's written, the "test first" code seems a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Just because `AsyncWaitHandle` finished without timing out does not mean it connected ***successfully***. You will need to call `tcpClient.EndConnect(` and see if it throws a exception, if no exception is thrown all is good, if not the connection is bad. Also, in your original method you where not closing the connection if you did successfully connect.

If you are using .NET 4.5 or newer it is easy to implement, use `ConnectAsync` instead of the begin/end pair and then you can use `await`.

```
public async Task<bool> IsAliveAsync(IPEndPoint ipEndPoint)
{
  if (ipEndPoint == null) return false;

  using(var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
  {
    var connectTask = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ipEndPoint.Address, ipEndPoint.Port)
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(1000);
    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

    bool isAlive;
    if(finishedTask == timeoutTask)
    {
        isAlive = false;
    }
    else
    {
      try
      {
          await connectTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
          isAlive = true;
      }
      catch
      {
        isAlive = false;
      }
    }

    return isAlive;
  }
}
```

Because I use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere I `await` it *should* be safe to call `.Result` on the task returned from this method instead of doing async/await all the way up your call stack.